# ClickOnce deployment to notify users(version update) having access to changed module

Tags: .net, clickonce, wrapper

I am using clickonce for deploying my .net windows application. When a module is modified/changed and deployed, All the users are notified for the version update once they try to launch the application. Since every time we do a change in the application in any of the module and deploy there will be an application version updated in the manifest and this version will be compared each time.
But what I need is to notify only those users who are having acess to the changed module. Other users should be using the old version.
Can we have a wrapper around clickonce to fulfill this requirement?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: what you have tried till now to achive this?? Placing some code in question is very useful to help you

Comment: @PavanKumar this is a deployment question, there is no code involved.

Comment: Exactly, As of now I am not sure whether we can achieve this or not. Can anyone suggest something.

Comment: well, I recommend publishing two applications, only updating one, left the other unchanged.